# strchr, memchr fails to locate the character

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to parse a string of format something like `1-3,5-7`. I need to read 1,3 and 5,7.

What I am doing

```
char *dup_string;
dup_string = strdup(data);
tok = strtok(dup_string, ",");
while (tok != NULL)
{
    char *rangeTok;
    rangeTok = (char *)memchr(tok, "-", strlen(tok));
    startpage = atoi(tok);
    if(rangeTok != NULL)
    {
         *rangeTok++;
         endpage = atoi(rangeTok);
    }
    else 
         endpage = startpage;

    tok = strtok(NULL,",");
}
```

Here `memchar` returning a badptr, I have tried using `strchr` which is also returning `batptr`. Any ideas why it is returning `badptr`.

FYI, earlier I tried:

```
tok = strchr(dupstring, ",");
```

which worked fine for sometime, and started returning `badptr`. I am not sure why it is doing that.

Comment: Please indent your code so that it's readable!

Comment: What's the idea behind the dereference in `*rangeTok++;`?

Comment: `memchr` takes in an int (character value), not a string. Change `memchr(tok, "-", strlen(tok));` to `memchr(tok, '-', strlen(tok));` and try again? Same deal with `strchr`.

Comment: Also, in the loop, the first argument of `strtok` should be `NULL`.

Comment: I have changed last `strtok` call, why is `strchr` is failing? as I said it was working for quite sometime and starting returning `badptr`. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the wrong argument to both `strchr` and `memchr`, as has already been pointed out. The second argument is an integer holding the value of a character, *not* a `const char *`.

This line

```
rangeTok = (char *)memchr(tok, "-", strlen(tok));
```

should be either

```
rangeTok = (char *)memchr(tok, '-', strlen(tok));
```

or preferably

```
rangeTok = strchr(tok, '-');
```

As an aside, what is this `badptr`?  Do you just mean `NULL`?

Answer (score 1):

The prototype of memchr() is as follows,  `void * memchr(void * ptr, int value, size_t num);`. But you are passing a string in `memchr(tok, "-", strlen(tok));` instead of an integer. The way you used `strtok()` is also wrong, It should be as follows,

```
tok = strtok(dup_string, ",");
while (tok != NULL)
{

   /* Body of Loop */


    tok = strtok(NULL,",");
}
```

On a first call, `strtok()` expects a string as the first argument, whose first character is used as the starting location to scan for tokens. In subsequent calls, the function expects a null pointer and uses the position right after the end of last token as the new starting location for scanning.

Comment: I agree but as far example here [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memchr/) I tried that way

Comment: The example you linked to uses single quotes; you're using double quotes.  There is a massive difference.

Answer (score 1):

try to use `sscanf()` in this way

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<string.h>

main()
{
    char *data = "1-3,5,8-9";
    char *ptr = data;
    int e, pos=0, startpage, endpage;
    while((e=sscanf(ptr, "%d-%d%n", &startpage, &endpage, &pos))>=1)
    {
        ptr+=pos;

        if(e==1)
             endpage = startpage;

        printf("start page %d ** end page %d\n",startpage,endpage);

        if (sscanf(ptr, " %*[,]%n", &pos) >= 0)
             ptr+=pos;
    }
}
```

Comment: the string not necessarily be in same format, it can be also like this `1-3,5,7-8,10` In this case I need will have 4 sets of startpage, endpage. if it is just `5` then both start and end page would be `5` How do I achieve this